# How to create a camera that combines both forced movement and smooth player following

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, game-development, lerp

## Context

So I'm making a clone of *Crossy Roads* where the camera follows the player. It does some linear interpolation (Lerp) after moving, and the camera starts moving away from the player in the positive direction (x-axis until camera reaches to a certain range where player is not visible enough). Things I have tried is by flagging it, but I think I'm doing it wrong.

## Problem

I have done my camera movements accordingly, but I am having an issue where the conditions are not properly met. I'm get the offset camera after not moving, but it does not the Lerp, and vice-versa. I want both to happen after a certain condition after the game starts. When the player moves, the camera follows it in Lerp. However, once the player is "Idle", its still Lerping. I want the camera to continue by itself and at the same time focus at the player's object.

## Example

### Camera with Lerp, but not moving away from the player

[image: Camera Lerps after moving, but it doesn't move away from the player]

### Camera moving away, but not following player with lerp

[image]

## Code

### `CameraController.cs`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

/*
** Camera following player (Smoothing and angle): https://youtu.be/4HpC--2iowE
** Maximo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXNFxQpp2qk&ab_channel=iHeartGameDev
** Moving character relative to camera: https://forum.unity.com/threads/moving-character-relative-to-camera.383086/
** Camera follow v2: https://youtu.be/Jpqt2gRHXtc?list=PLq_nO-RwB516fNlRBce0GbtJSfysAjOgU
*/

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public PlayerControl playerControlScript;
    private Vector3 newCameraPos;
    public bool stillIdle;


    void Start()
    {
        stillIdle = false; 
        PlayerControl playerControlScript = GetComponent<PlayerControl>();
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        if (playerControlScript.GetfirstInput()) //True
        {
            stillIdle = true;
            newCameraPos = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, playerControlScript.transform.position, Time.deltaTime);
            transform.position = new Vector3(newCameraPos.x, 1, newCameraPos.z);
        }
        if (stillIdle)
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 0.69f * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y, transform.position.z); //Moving camera away effect
    }
}
```

### `PlayerControl.cs`

```
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool firstInput;
    Vector3 startPos;
    Vector3 endPos;
    public bool GetfirstInput() //I was learning how to have a Get function while my member was private from another script file
    {
        return firstInput;
    }
    void Update()
    {
         if (Input.GetButtonDown("up") || Input.GetButtonDown("left") || Input.GetButtonDown("right") || Input.GetButtonDown("down"))
        {
            //if game starts
            {
                //Other variables being initialized here
                firstInput = true;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

## Hierarchy/Inspector

### Main Camera

[image]

### Player Object

[image]

Some help would be appreciate it. I feel I have been staring at this problem and I bet it is something minimal and small from just thinking it.

Let me know if you need clarifications. I'm happy to edit and answer them for everyone

Answer (score 1):

1. If player in your game does not change, you don't have to find the player reference in each `LateUpdate()`.
2. I notice that once `stillIdle` is set true, it never goes back to false, is this your intention to do that?
3. You call `Lerp` when `playerControlScript.GetfirstInput()` is true, so maybe we need to look at its implementation. Maybe it turns true in some conditions you do not intend it to.

Maybe Try this

```
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    private bool _hasFireFirstInput = false;
    private bool _isIdle = true;

    public bool IsIdle => _isIdle;
    public bool HasFireFirstInput => _hasFireFirstInput;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal") || Input.GetButton("Vertical"))
        {
            _hasFireFirstInput = true;
            _isIdle = false;


            Vector3 pos = transform.position;
            pos = new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z + .2f * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.position = pos;
        }
        else
        {
            _isIdle = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I use `Input.GetButton()` rather than `Input.GetButtonDown()`, since the later only return true at the frame the button is pressed, meaning that if i long-press the button, it will return false after the next frame.

```
public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] PlayerControl _playerControlScript;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 _offset;
    [SerializeField] float _lerpSpeed;

    bool _iskeepLerping = false;
    float _lerpVal = 0f;

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (!_playerControlScript.HasFireFirstInput)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (_playerControlScript.IsIdle)
        {
            MoveAway();
        }
        else
        {
            Lerp();
        }
    }

    private void MoveAway()
    {
        _iskeepLerping = false;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 0.69f * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }

    private void Lerp()
    {
        if (!_iskeepLerping)
        {
            _lerpVal = 0f;
        }
        
        Vector3 newCameraPos = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, _playerControlScript.transform.position + _offset, _lerpVal);
        transform.position = newCameraPos;
        _lerpVal += _lerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        _iskeepLerping = true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: the 2. point is true, thus I'm having issues how I can maintain the condition at the same time without messing up. I have updated more of the post with examples

Comment: You can use public property to get the value of a private field, without using public method, like `public bool FirstInput => firstInput;`

Comment: Like literally writing it `public bool FirstInput => firstInput;` ? I didn't know this

Comment: So `firstInput` basically means whether player has fired input. And since `playerControlScript.GetfirstInput()` return the value of `firstInput,` which means the `Lerp` part will always get called after player firing first input.

Comment: I think you need a way to tell the camera script that player is idle, and turn the `Lerp` part off when this condition is meet.

Comment: Would you suggest to have another variable to check within my `playerControlScript.GetfirstInput()`?

Comment: Ok so I'm reading this: https://gamedevbeginner.com/the-right-way-to-lerp-in-unity-with-examples/

Maybe the way I'm using the Lerp method is not correct because I'm just calling it without any other way of checking when to turn off the Lerp. I think this is a good direction to look into it

Comment: @ZeidTisnes No, I suggest using another property to check whether player is idle.

Comment: Curretly, the property being used for `GetfirstInput()` is being called in my `PlayerControl.cs` file. I will make another property for either the player or camera that checks the current `Lerp` time. If it goes over `1.0f`, I can switch the behavior to move the camera away ONLY if is above `1.0f`

Comment: @ZeidTisnes I edited my answer, maybe it can help.

Comment: Oh, I see it. The way you using lerp seems strange, for the third parameter should be a interpolated value (0~1). But that is independent to the controlling flow of your  `LateUpdate()`.

Comment: How should I do this then? Should I check if my ratio is at `1.0f`, then switch to normal camera movement then in my `CameraControl.cs` instead of having `Time.deltaTime`?

Comment: Which question is you asking? 
1) How to implement the Lerp move? Or, 
2) How to control the camera movement from player's movement states? 
I think they are different questions, and  should be handled separately.

Comment: For `Lerp` movement when the player is not idle. My understanding is when the interpolation happens at a certain rate, I should change the behavior and switch to idle. Once I'm idle, I want the camera to move normally away from the player without any `Lerp`. Thus I was referencing the link above and was curious if the behaviors can be handled depending in the player's state `IsIdle` like you have.

Comment: You mean the camera script Can Set the player's state to Idle? I think the camera's movement should depend on player's movement, not the other way around. Or you mean when the camera `Lerp` close enough to player, it'll set to `MoveAway` move?

Comment: Basically, the `CameraControl.cs` checks the `PlayerControl.cs` script, which contains the `IsIdle` boolean. That way, it checks whenever the `IsIdle` triggered and communicate with the camera movement what to do. Now, once the `Lerp` is close enough to the player, this `IsIdle` will trigger a different camera movement to `MoveAway` from the player.

Comment: @ZeidTisnes I've edit my test code in answer, it works for me. Maybe it can help.

Comment: I'm getting the effect as intended now. I did a little bit of more adjustments in order to work. Next step is to edit and tweaking! Thank you very much :D